# ¿Como puedo evitar que el texto se desborde en una tabla responsive?

Tags: php, mysql

Quisiera evitar que se alargue de esta forma , probe con text-overflow:elipsis pero no me hace el cambio ya que es flexible, la tabla esta hecha con boostrap 5 , por lo cuál me gustaría evitar este problema , y abusando de su amabilidad quisiera evitar que al mostrar los registros el texto en negrita no se mueva por la cantidad de texto, de antemano muchas gracias! Adjunto imagen :

[image: Imagen del texto desbordado]

[image: Imagen que muestra la informacion]

Y este es el codigo para mostrar la informacion:

```html
 <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <?php
                    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<h5><strong>Número Registro: </strong>' . $row["iddaem"] . '</h5>';
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo '<h5><strong>Código Documento: </strong>' . $row["cod_doc"] . '</h5>';
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo '<h5><strong>Fecha Registro:</strong>' . $row["fecha_registro"] . '</h5>';
                        echo "<br>";

                        echo '<h5><strong>Hora Registro:</strong>' . $row["hora_registro"] . '</h5>';
                        echo "<br>";

                        echo '<h5><strong>Materia del Registro:</strong>' . $row["materia"] . '</h5>';
                        echo "<br>";

                        echo '<h5><strong>Usuario:</strong>' . $row["usuario"] . '</h5>';
                    }
                    ?>
                    <a class='btn btn-success btn-raised btn-xs' href="daem_editar.php?iddaem=<?php echo $iddaem ?>">Actualizar</a>
                </div>
```

Comment: Agrega el html de la tabla.

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo! , ya lo solucione era algo muy facil jajaja ! , Igualmente gracias por la colaboracion!!

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar propiedad word-break de css

```
word-break: break-all;
```

## ejemplo:

```css
.break {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:green;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.nobreak {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="break">Honorificabilitudinitatibus califragilisticexpialidocious Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu 次の単語グレートブリテンおよび北アイルランド連合王国で本当に大きな言葉</div>
</br>
<div class="nobreak">Honorificabilitudinitatibus califragilisticexpialidocious Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu 次の単語グレートブリテンおよび北アイルランド連合王国で本当に大きな言葉</div>
```

referencia:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break